# WCF Service proof of concept for Security

Tags: c#, wcf

I am brand new to WCF. Never created one before. I have been asked to create a proof of concept for our team, and the spec is: "We need a method of securing and locking down our webservices so that the communication is secure, and the call can be authenticated to be from a valid client."

That's it. We have a few sub systems that speak to each other with unauthenticated WCF calls, I believe. They want this to be locked down, using a token or 'shared key'.

I'd like to create a small console app, which acts as a web service server, and then a client console app, which speaks to it, and it looks like a good approach would be uisng extra headers (I read that on here somewhere) and IClientMessageInspector (??). Does this seem like a valid kick off?

But I am new to WCF.. and have no idea what IClientMessageInspector is. It seems like I can make a custom method there to check for tokens or something in the WCF call?

I would like an example, but am battling to find out, and the terminology is killing me. Hopefully someone can assist.

Comment: Although I'm not WCF guru and I don't have a great suggestion, I *highly* suggest reading a WCF book.  Because the framework itself was so configurable in many respects, I had a hard time feeling confident knowing where to start.

Comment: Do you need more than to just use the default wsHttpBinding?

Comment: @JohnSaunders - I am not sure. I am trying to read about basic WCF, so am not sure what wsHttpBinding is. I'll google it. Edit: Just checked, we're using BasicHttpBidning - but we can change this - I believe.

Comment: You _really_ need to go learn some WCF basics, and not just google for things. See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/wcf/info for some resources.

Comment: From what you describe, it sounds like Windows Identity Foundation is the way to go.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh545447.aspx and here is an example of a claims aware web service: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/vstudio/Claims-Aware-Web-Service-1d55facc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest route is using BasicHttpBinding with transport security (SSL), each client can have it's own (or a shared) certificate which is used for authentication and your data is encrypted as well (SSL).

Only clients with a known certificate will be able to call the service. Here is a good article on the subject [BasicHttpBinding with Client Certificate](http://robbincremers.me/2011/12/27/wcf-transport-security-and-client-certificate-authentication-with-self-signed-certificates/)